# Laravel website behind the reverse proxy and subfolder?

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, reverse-proxy, laravel-routing

I have a Laravel website with LAMP stack and host on a ec2 server. I setup the Virtual Host configuration for the host name `www.abc.com` and it works fine. One day, The client said they want to use their domain to visit the website like `www.client.com/abc`. They use the reverse proxy to point our ec2 server. The first problem we met is the virtual host has failed and we fixed it by adding server alias setting.

```
ServerAlias www.client.com
```

The url has connected to the server correctly and the second problem is coming up. Because of the subfolder of the url `www.client.com/abc`, all the assets paths are failed. For example, we had fonts, styles and js paths that generated by laravel-mix:

```
{
    "/js/app.js": "/js/app.js",
    "/css/app.css": "/css/app.css",
    "/js/login.js": "/js/login.js"
}
```

Those paths are absolute and it turns to 404 found on the website if we use the `mix()` helper function to load assets. The rendered url on the blade pages are wrong.

It would be

```
http://www.client.com/js/app.js
```

instead of

```
http://www.client.com/abc/js/app.js
```

And the fonts loaded from the vendor and styles, which use the relative paths and are converted to absolute as well. So we had to workaround this by adding the option  `processCssUrls: false` to webpack.mix.js.

The third problem is the redirection when user logs in out. The defaults redirect url is `/`. I know we can change the redirect urls in middleware and controllers but it feels like so much workaround over this. Is there any better way to solve those problems?
To declare the question again, how to setup a Laravel project behind the reverse proxy with subfolder?

```
http://www.example.com/laravel
```